# Calling cheerio.load inside each loop

Tags: node.js, meteor, web-scraping, cheerio

So the basic server JS **scraper** in Meteor.

The pattern is kinda simple. Script finds certain links, then loads content from them and stores the content in variable.

Script keeps crashing when loading cheerio inside loop.
Where's the catch ? What's the best implementation for this purpose ?

```
  Meteor.methods({
    loadPage: function () {
      result = Meteor.http.get("http://url.com");
      $ = cheerio.load(result.content);
      $('.class').each(function(i,elem){
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        var title = $(this).text();
        var $ = cheerio.load(Meteor.http.get(link).content);
        var postContent = $('.classOnLoadedPage');
        Images.insert(
          {
            link: link,
            title: title,
            postContent:  postContent
          });
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @BidhanA Exception while invoking method 'loadPage' TypeError: undefined is not a function and points to "var link ... " inside loop, but after I delete cherio load inside loop all is ok.

Comment: Did you `require` cheerio properly?

Comment: @BidhanA yes) it works OK if not calling it from inside each loop.

Comment: Try adding `console.log($)` right below `$ = cheerio.load(result.content);` to see if $ has any content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got exactly the same problem today. Turns out it is problem with cheerio itself. Rather old version of it has this bug. You have to use newer version and then it works.

the most downloaded cheerio package in atmospherejs `mrt:cheerio` wraps `cheerio 0.12.3`, while current version in npm is `cheerio 0.19.0`

add `rclai89:cheerio` instead of `mrt:cheerio` and it will deliver `cheerio 0.18.0`, and with this version load within loop works perfectly.